# Search item as a "Tool Bar" in google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`m trying to add "Search Item" option in the tool bar.
Basically, I have 6 different tabs in the same google sheet, but the # of items in each sheet is too many that users may not be able to find.

Is there way to add such tool in tool bar using Google sheet Script?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lbfbMUhwKGG0CJ1tJuXVmwCRPAox_1dIATffhKVjkQM/edit?usp=sharing

Above is the link to the sample data

The data is generated from API for ad server system

In my real data, that "Creative" column has about > 1000 unique entries

Is there potentially, way to put option in a toolbar that does the "creative" search job, that can tell us creative "c6" was found in "first" tab, second row..

But search those items in only the "unhidden" tab

I`m not sure where I should start this with.. given the multiple tabs

Can someone please provide me suggestions?

Comment: In order to correctly your situation, can I ask you about your goal? 1. When I saw your shared Spreadsheet,I thought that you might want to search the rows from each column "A" (``Creative``) using a value. Is my understanding correct? 2. What is the tool bar you think? 3. In your tag, "Javascript" is used. Do you want to achieve this using Javascript which is not Google Apps Script? 4. Can you provide your current script? 5. What is the tab of "RAW"? In your actual Spreadsheet, is the tab you don't want to search included? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, oh you again!! I don`t understand when you say poor English skill when your sentence is perfect, anyways I remember you! you answered my previous question and was able to accomplish the task perfectly... :) So for this task, 1) I am trying to search items in "Creative" column and return that actual item in "Creative" column + Impression + Click values (numeric values adjacent to that creative basically..) 2) Tool bar as in one of those tool bars that show up at the top of Google Sheet.(Something right next to "Data", "Tools") 3) No, through Google Sheet App Script!

Comment: To be continued.. 5) RAW is the raw data that is the origin for all the separate tabs there. (I didn`t include it here) And yes, that is the tab I don`t want to be searched since that is just raw data. 4) For the script, frankly speaking, I haven`t written specifically for this tool-bar task, but i have the API call, raw data transformation and split into the separate tab code.. Should we look into this code as well? I really have no clue how I should start for creating this tool-bar...

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I understood about your goal as the following flow. 1. Input a search value. You want to run Google Apps Script by the menu bar. 2. Search the column "A" for each sheet using the search value, and when the searched value is found at the column "A", it retrieves the row. There are sheets you don't want to use for searching. Can you tell me whether my understanding is correct? And as an additional question, where do you want to show the searched results?

Comment: Yes!! That is 100% correct. But for the results part, a few modifications.. so the results will include a) which tab that item is included in b) associated impression values / click values from each tab.

Comment: So it will look like, in a box format, "Creative A1 was found in the following tabs:" "tab name1, Impression: 300, click: 25" , "tab name2, Impression: 20, click:20", "tab name3, Impression:10, click:15" , something like this...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that the flow is correct. About the result you want to show, I couldn't understand yet. For example, when the result is returned as JSON object, can you create the script for retrieving the result you want?

Comment: Not sure if I would be able to retrieve JSON object. Would it possible to show the results in pop-up box format? so that it can be user-friendly somehow?

Comment: Can you add the sample result you want to your question? By this, I would like to confirm about it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So I just updated the google sheet there https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lbfbMUhwKGG0CJ1tJuXVmwCRPAox_1dIATffhKVjkQM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please look at the "Answer Tab" for the sample of the results!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize. By the way, you want to use Google Apps Script. So I modified the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Input a search value.

  - You want to run Google Apps Script by the menu bar.
- Search the column "A" for each sheet using the search value, and when the searched value is found at the column "A", it retrieves the row.

  - There are sheets you don't want to use for searching.
- You want to show the result as follows.

  ```
  Creative "C6" was found in "Second", "fifth" tab
  Second Tab: Impression:100 / Click:100
  Fifth Tab: Impression:100 / Click:100
  ```

I understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of them.

#### Flow:

1. When Spreadsheet is opened, the custom menu is added.
2. Run the script from "Show prompt" of the custom menu. By this, a dialog box is opened.
3. Input a search text to the text input field, and click "ok" button.
4. At the script, the rows are searched with TextFinder using the inputted search text.
5. Show the result by a dialog box as a sample.

#### Sample script:

**Before you run the script, please set the sheet name to `sheets`.**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}

function showPrompt() {
  // Please set the sheet name you want to use for searching.
  var sheets = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"];

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var res = ui.prompt('Sample', 'Input search text:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var button = res.getSelectedButton();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    var findText = res.getResponseText();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var header = "Creative \"" + findText + "\" was found in ";
    var values = "";
    var object = sheets.reduce(function(obj, sheetName, i) {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(findText);
      var searchedRows = textFinder.findAll().reduce(function(ar, e) {
        if (e.getColumn() == 1) {
          var row = sheet.getRange(e.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
          if (row[0] === findText) {
            ar.push(row);
            header += '"' + sheetName + '"' + (i == sheets.length - 1 ? " tab\n" : ", ");
            values += sheetName + " Tab: Impression:" + row[1] + " / Click:" + row[2] + "\n";
          }
        }
        return ar;
      }, []);
      if (searchedRows.length > 0) obj[sheetName] = searchedRows;
      return obj;
    }, {});
    Logger.log(object);
    ui.alert(header + values);
  }
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a sample script. please modify this for your situation.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll())
- [Prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

### Edit:

- When the searched text was not found, you want to show "The creative you just searched for does not exist, please go back and check if there is any typo!".

In order to reflect your above request to the script, please modify above script as follows.

#### From:

```
ui.alert(header + values);
```

#### To:

```
if (Object.keys(object).length > 0) {
  ui.alert(header.slice(0, -2) + " tab\n" + values);
} else {
  ui.alert("The creative you just searched for does not exist, please go back and check if there is any typo!");
}
```

Comment: Hey Tanaike, I just tried, this is working perfectly as intended again!! Only thing was that when we assign this sheets variable, ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"], can we make this entry come from the raw data itself? Because the tabs are auto-generated whenever there is new entry.

Comment: Never mind, I figured! using   var sheets = new Array()
  var sheetss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheetss.length ; i++) sheets.push( [sheetss[i].getName() ] )

Comment: Hey Tanaike, Sorry, instead of this, I have another question.. In case the creative wasn`t found, is it possible to show "Error: Not Found" Message somehow?

Comment: @Jason1993 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, when there are no values in the column of ``Creative``, no error occurs. If you want to use other format of the data, can you post it as new question? Because one question should have one answer. At that time, please close this question. By this, other user can see your question as the resolved question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, so I meant, when the creative name you searched for doesn`t exist in any of the sheet, then prompt the message, "Creative Not Found!" (basically, not necessarily an error, but if (row[0] !== findText), this case)

Comment: @Jason1993 I apologize that in my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. Can you share the spreadsheet for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Jason1993 About ``if (row[0] !== findText)``, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can you provide the detail information about it?

Comment: Yup! so I just added tab named "Difference Case" in the same google sheet there. This is the case I`m trying to achieve!

Comment: @Jason1993 You want to show ``"The creative you just searched for does not exist, please go back and check if there is any typo!"``, when the searched text was not found. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes! 100% correct, I tried accomlishing this task by modifying that      if (searchedRows.length > 0) obj[sheetName] = searchedRows;
      return obj; part by adding in "}else{" statement, but it won`t let me generate that results

Comment: @Jason1993 Thank you for replying. I added the modified script for achieving your additional request. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you again, and I will follow up if I have any other questions about the codes in detail!

Comment: For that header.slice(0,-2) statement, what was the purpose of this? Wouldn`t using just header itself work too?

Comment: @Jason1993 I used ``header.slice(0, -2)`` to remove the last ``, `` of ``Creative "C6" was found in "Second", "fifth", tab`` which is the header. This is used for the format (``Creative "C6" was found in "Second", "fifth" tab``) you want. If you can confirm using ``ui.alert(header + " tab\n" + values);``. If you can use ``Creative "C6" was found in "Second", "fifth", tab``, please use ``ui.alert(header + " tab\n" + values);``. Is my understanding your additional question correct? I apologize for my poor English skill.